# Sed capture group to replace nth column value in csv by matching given first two column values

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have mysql dump file in the below format and I want to replace the 15th column value by matching given values with first two columns.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES 
 ('20','ramesh',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,),
 ('30','raghav',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,),
 ('40','balaji',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,);
```

Expected output:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES 
 ('20','ramesh',,,,,,,,,,,,,'0',,,),
 ('30','raghav',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,),
 ('40','balaji',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,);
```

Here sed should match given empId and empName as '20' and 'ramesh' and replace 15th column of value '1' to '0'. In between columns 3,8 and 9 have json or xml string values

I tried with below sed capture group but it is not working.

```
sed -i -e "s|(\('20\)',\('ramesh'\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),'1'|(\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9,\10,\11,\12,\13,\14,'0'|" employees.sql
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do post expected output in your question also to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: If in real life "In between columns 3,8 and 9 have json or xml string values" then in the example in your question those columns should have json or xml string values, especially if they include quotes and commas. Please [edit] your examples to show truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: does the json/xml data contain single quotes, or linefeeds that break the data across multiple lines?

Comment: please update the question with an explanation of what you mean by *`is not working`* ... you get an error (and if so, what is the full error)? you get no output? you get the wrong output (and if so, what is the output you get)? no changes are made to the data? something else?

Comment: sed supports only 9 capture groups, you can reference only `\1` through `\9`.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for `FPAT` and the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    FPAT = "([^" OFS "]*)|('([^']|'')*')"
}
match($0,/(^\s*\()(.*)(\).*)/,a) {
    $0 = a[2]
    if ( ($1 == "'20'") && ($2 =="'ramesh'") ) {
        $15 = "'0'"
    }
    $0 = a[1] $0 a[3]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES
 ('20','ramesh',,,,,,,,,,,,,'0',,,),
 ('30','raghav',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,),
 ('40','balaji',,,,,,,,,,,,,'1',,,);
```

If you want to run the awk script using `awk 'script'` instead of `awk -f scriptfile` as above then just change every `'` in the script to `\047`.

The above assumes your CSV doesn't contain newlines. If it does then see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for how to parse it using awk.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(^\s*\(('\'')20\2,\2ramesh\2,{13}\2)1\2/\10\2/' file
```

Using pattern matching and back references, replace the `1` in the 15th field of a line with `0`, where the first two fields match `20` and `ramesh`.

N.B. The second back reference is a `'` character which is also matched the LHS of the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

The following only accepts text you provide (may not be generic).

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; q="\047"};
$1 ~ q"20"q && $2 ~ q"ramesh"q{$15=q"0"q}; 1
' file
```